# hardcrop images in gutenberg "latest posts" block

Tags: images, block-editor

I like the gutenberg "latest posts" block. The problem I have with it is that it doesn't hardcrop images that users upload to the posts.  Is there a way to choose a hard-cropped or custom size that I have created through the `add_image_size()` function?

I don't really have any code, but I think this question is on topic because it's purely about wordpress core.  I'm sorry if it isn't!

What I have used to create my custom image size is this though:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'aeroleds_image_sizes' );
function aeroleds_image_sizes() {
    add_image_size( 'banner-image', 400, 300, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Latest Posts block uses (`wp.data.select( 'core/block-editor' ).getSettings()` to get) the image sizes in the editor settings which can be filtered via the [`block_editor_settings` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/block_editor_settings/) in PHP:

> `apply_filters( 'block_editor_settings', array $editor_settings, WP_Post $post )`
>
> Filters the settings to pass to the block editor.

And the setting name used for the image sizes is `imageSizes`.

So for example, to make the custom `banner-image` size be available in the featured image size dropdown (in the Latest Posts block's settings):

```php
add_filter( 'block_editor_settings', 'wpse_375600' );
function wpse_375600( $editor_settings ) {
    $editor_settings['imageSizes'][] = [
        'slug' => 'banner-image',
        'name' => 'Banner Image',
    ];

    return $editor_settings;
}
```

And in addition to that the filter being specific to the block editor, your callback can also get access to the post being edited, which is the second parameter (`$post`) in the filter hook as you can see above. So you could for example filter the settings only for certain posts.

**Resources:**

- [The Latest Posts block on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-library/src/latest-posts)
- [The Block Editor's Data » `getSettings()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/data/data-core-block-editor/#getSettings)
- [Editor Filters » Editor Settings](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/editor-filters/#editor-settings)

Comment: Two notes:
1) `block_editor_settings` is deprecated in WordPress 5.8 and so use `block_editor_settings_all` instead.
2) Using the other answer with `image_size_names_choose` also works and will support the Classic Editor (and other interfaces) as a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you have to also pass your custom image thumbnail sizes to the filter  `image_size_names_choose`. I tried it and this works for displaying custom images sizes as choices in the latest posts dropdown:

```
add_filter('image_size_names_choose', function( $sizes ){
    return array_merge( $sizes, [ 'banner-image' => 'banner image' ] );
});
```

This blog explains a similar issue, so I tried his suggestion.
https://talhasariyuerek.com/en/show-all-image-sizes-in-gutenberg-mediaupload-wordpress/

And by the way, the Gutenberg component that controls that dropdown is https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/image-size-control

Comment: Actually Sally CJ's answer seems like the better solution